# Looping through symmetric matrices

Tags: for-loop

I want to plot all the elements of two matrices which have the same indices together. So if the two matrices

`A = [1 4; 4 5]` and `B = [2 3; 3 6]` are given

the pairs to be plottet would be `(1/2)`, `(4/3)`, `(4/3)`, `(5/6)`.

But the matrices in my code are symmetric, and I would want to avoid looping through the entire matrices (such that if we have the `(4/3)` plotted already I would avoid looping through were this pair of values occurs again). How can I do that?
With the current code:

```
 for i = 1:size(A,1)
    for j = 1:size(A,1)     
      plot(A(i,j),B(i,j))
     end
 end
```

I obviously have redundancies..

Comment: Is the part of the matrices you want to traverse as triangles? If so then you should loop i from 1 to n but loop j from i to n rather from 1 to n. I'll provide a proper answer presently if this is the case.

Comment: exact. so if we have e.g. [0 1 2; 1 0 3; 2 3 0] and [ 0 5 6; 5 0 7; 6 7 0] we basically can consider the upper triangles and plot (0,0), (1,5), (2,6), (3,7)..the main diagonal is actually all (0,0)..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to traverse just one triangle of the matrix.

You can do this by looping through i from 1 to n then looping j through i to n.

This iterates through n(n+1)/2 rather than n*n entries.

```
for i = 1:size(A,1)
    for j = i:size(A,1)     
      plot(A(i,j),B(i,j))
     end
end
```

Comment: we forgot the "hold on" command (else it plots one point only), else perfect. thank you!